# Sqlite multithreading operations

Tags: database, multithreading, sqlite, nsoperation, read-write

I had applied multiple operation on my sqlite3 database but my some operation does not made changes on DB.
So please explain my following queries:

How to make single data base connection throwout the app in sqlite?
how to handled multi threading in sqlite?
please explain.

Comment: SQLite is thread-aware. So details, please... DETAILS :)

Comment: Read https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html and https://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html